# Building Opengl 3+ in ubuntu under virtualbox/vmware

Tags: virtualization, opengl

For a computer graphics class we will be developing opengl 3+ applications. I have installed ubuntu under both vmware and virtualbox, and installed there respective guest additions.

If I run

```
   glxinfo | grep "OpenGL version"
```

I get

OpenGL version string: 2.1 Chromium 1.9

Is there any way that OpenGL 3+ is supported in a virtual machine (with ubuntu as guest?)

Info: The host is Windows 8 64bit Intel i7-920, nVidia 560Ti GPU.

Thank you in advance!

EDIT: Forgot to mention that because this is academic, software rendering using openGL 3+ is also ok. I find Mesa3D promising, but can't find enough information on how to install in ubuntu and force software rendering (using openGL 3+). Any information is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You could try installing the proprietary Nvidia drivers.  The Nvidia 560Ti you have should support OpenGL 3.0.  This page should help:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/Nvidia